# How to compare cells in Excel based on another comparison

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison, coordinates

This isn't precisely what I'm working on but it'll do for the purposes of the help I require.
I have a spreadsheet in which I have coordinates. I'm trying to see which coordinates are horizontally adjacent 
So I want to perform the operation: if cell value that contains Y1 coordinate occurs in a another column of Y values then I want to check whether there's an X2 value that's +1 (or -1) away from the X1 value that's associated with the initial Y1 value.

```
#   T(X) T(Y) U(X) U(Y)
1   1    2    2    3
2   2    2    3    2
3   4    3    4    2
4   2    3    2    2
5   7    3    5    3
```

So if I were to use the table above and were looking at the first non-heading row I want the script to recognise there's a 2 in the T(Y) column, check to see whether there are 2's in the U(Y) column. And then just check to see whether there was a U(X) value that was +1 or -1 the T(X) associated with the T(Y) value of 2. 
I did manage to come up with something but it was flawed because it only worked as the coordinates happened to be aligned. I.e, there were many repetitions of x coordinates but that isn't always going to be the case.
What I have...=IF(AND(ISERROR(MATCH(G23,I23:I288,0))=FALSE,(ISERROR(MATCH(H23-1,J23:J288,0))=FALSE)),"Output1",IF(AND(ISERROR(MATCH(G23,I23:I288,0))=FALSE,(ISERROR(MATCH(H23+1,J23:J288,0))=FALSE)),"Output2", "0"))
The missing link is that I want to restrict my x-coordinate search to the "search result" of when T(Y)=U(Y)

Comment: should th T(Y) and U(Y) be an exact match?

Comment: Yes @IbrahimHassan.